# How can I store lambda with capture this in class as parameter?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, lambda

I have a problem with storing lambda expression with capturing "this" pointer in class as parameter. I made typedef like this:

```
typedef void(*func)();
```

This code below works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void(*func)();

class A {
public:
    func f;
};

class B {
public:
    A *a;

    B() {
        a = new A();
        a->f = [](){
            printf("Hello!");
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    B *b = new B();
    b->a->f();
    return 0;
}
```

There is no capturing yet but when I want to capture "this" pointer in lambda it throws an error. How can I make typedef with capturing? I want to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void(*func)();

class A {
public:
    func f;
};

class B {
public:
    A *a;

    B() {
        a = new A();

        //There is a problem with [this]
        a->f = [this](){
            //Method from class B using "this" pointer
            this->p();
        };
    }
    void p() {
        printf("Hello!");
    }
};

int main() {
    B *b = new B();
    b->a->f();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Explain me please. Thanks.

Comment: Using `std::function` instead of a plain function pointer should help.

Comment: I think the main problem is, that `this` inside the lambda would refer to the lambda (as a lambda is an anonymous functor). Have you tried using a proxy like `auto self = this;` and capture `self` inside the lambda?

Comment: Capturing lambdas are *not* convertible to function pointers.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using raw pointers to own resources? You should probably just use automatic objects for everything in this program.

Comment: @MFH No, a lambda capturing `this` captures the "containing" `this`. See [expr.prim.lambda]§7

Comment: @Angew: You're right! Must have missed that (or was led to believe otherwise by a nonconforming implementation...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to convert from a lambda with a capture to a function pointer, because a lambda with a capture contains more information than a function pointer (it contains not only the address of the function, but also the variables that have been captured).

Change `typedef void(*func)();` to `typedef std::function<void()> func;` to get something which is able to hold any copyable function type.

Answer (score 3):

As Angew said above, you should be using the `std::function` class template, not just a function pointer.  Your code would become this (copying from 2nd example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;



class A {
public:
    std::function<void> f;
};

class B {
public:
    shared_ptr<A> a;  // Better ownership

    B() 
     : a(new A())
    {
        // Now this should work
        a->f = [this](){
            //Method from class B using "this" pointer
            this->p();
        };
        // Note, you could just do this instead of a lambda:
        // a->f = bind(b::p, this);
    }
    void p() {
        printf("Hello!");
    }
};

int main() {
    B *b = new B();
    b->a->f();
    return 0;
}
```

I also added automatic cleanup of `A` via a smart pointer, in addition to the correct callable object, and added the code to show you how to do this with `std::bind` as well.